# Run a script each time I add a new npm dependency to my project

Tags: npm

I'm using webpack to build a react application. I just applied some optimization to reduce build times in development mode, following this article: http://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/optimizing-webpack/.

It works great but the downside is that I now must remember to rebuild the vendors file each time I add a new dependency.

Is there any way to configure npm through the `package.json` to automatically run a script whenever a new dependency is added ?

Clarifications about the desired behavior:

I'd like npm to run a script each time I do:

`npm install --save a-new-dependency`

Comment: Have you tried defining `postinstall` in `scripts`?

Comment: `postintall` is meant for packages themselves

Comment: but yes, I tried anyway and the script is not executed after adding a dependency on the project

Comment: I need a `postinstalldependency` :p

Comment: Perhaps you should have given a [mcve] and asked why your `postinstall` doesn't work.

Comment: To further explain what I meant, i'd like something like https://github.com/grncdr/npm-watch but automatically handled by npm for dependencies